Simulation vs formula-based power calculations for longitudinal studies: why the large differences?
I would like to understand the reason for different results obtained with power calculations using formula-based methods vs simulations in the context of mixed linear models of longitudinal RCTs. I am relatively ignorant and would be most grateful for some insight.
Let's look at an example vignette, slightly modified from "Power for linear models of longitudinal data with applications to Alzheimer’s Disease Phase II study design" 1
Consider an Alzheimer’s disease RCT in which assessments are taken every three months for 18 months (7 visits). We assume the smallest detectable effect size of the trial drug is .75 points on the cognitive portion of the Alzheimer’s Disease Assessment Scale (ADAS-Cog). Assume subjects are divided 1:1 between placebo and drug arms. From pilot studies, we assume the random intercept to have a variance of 55, the random slope to have a variance of 24, and a residual variance of 10. The correlation between random slope term and random intercept term is 0.8.
For the purposes of constructing a mixed linear model to this scenario, let's assume that the ADAS-Cog declines by 10 points per year and assume an average baseline (intercept) of -10.
For simplicity, assume no attrition and that the ADAS-Cog declines linearly over time. Assume random slopes and intercept come from a bivariate normal distribution.
First calculate the power by formula using the edland.linear.power function from the longpower package. Let's determine power for a total of 100 subjects:
install.packages("longpower")
library(longpower)
sig2.i = 55
# var of random slope
sig2.s = 24
# residual var
sig2.e = 10
# covariance of slope and intercept
cov.s.i <- 0.8*sqrt(sig2.i)*sqrt(sig2.s)
t = seq(0,1.5,0.25)

out <- edland.linear.power(delta=.75, t=t, sig2.int = sig2.i, sig.b0b1 = cov.s.i, sig2.s = sig2.s, sig2.e = sig2.e, sig.level=0.05, n = 50, lambda = 1)


Out:
power ~ 0.1
Note that the GEE-based Diggle formula from the long power package produces an almost identical result.2
Now let's try a simulation:
install.packages(MASS)
install.packages("lmerTest")
library(MASS) # for MVRNORM
library(lmerTest)

nsim = 500
pval <- numeric()

for (i in 1:nsim) {
  
# total number of subjects  
ni = 100

#var of random intercept
sig2.i = 55
# var of random slope
sig2.s = 24
# residual var
sig2.e = 10
#correlation between intercept and slope
rho = .8
# covariance of slope and intercept
cov.s.i <- rho*sqrt(sig2.i)*sqrt(sig2.s)

psi = matrix(c(sig2.i,cov.s.i, cov.s.i, sig2.s), 2, 2)
RE = mvrnorm(ni, mu=c(0,0), psi)
colnames(RE) = c("ints","slopes");  t(round(RE,2))
time = seq(0,1.5,0.25)  # visits
nj   = as.numeric(length(time))     

#make dataframe of covariates and random errors
df = data.frame(ID   = rep(1:ni,   each=nj, times = 1), 
                  time = (rep(time,   times=ni)),
                  group = rep(gl(2, (ni*nj)/2, labels = c                             ("placebo", "drug"))),
                  time.group <- c(rep(0, each = (ni*nj)/2, 
                                      times = 1),as.numeric(rep(1:nj, times=(ni/2)))),
                  RE.i = rep(RE[,1], each=nj),
                  RE.s = rep(RE[,2], each=nj)
                  )   

colnames(df) = c('ID', 'time' ,'group','time.group','RE.i', 'RE.s')

e <- rnorm(n=ni*nj, mean=0, sd=sqrt(sig2.e)) #residual error
df$e = e

#generate y
y = with(df, (-10 + RE.i) + (-10 + RE.s)*time + .75*(time.group)  + e)
df$y = y


m1 <- lmer(y ~ time*group + (time| ID), data = df, REML = F, control = lmerControl(optimizer ="Nelder_Mead"))

summary(m1)
out <- anova(m1)
pval[i] <- out$'Pr(>F)'[3]

}

power <- sum(pval < 0.05)/nsim

The power is approximately 0.8.
The question is why the huge discrepancy between formula-based and simulation-based power calculations of the treatment effect in a longitudinal RCT?
Have I made fundamental errors with the calculations?
Is there a genuine difference in the distribution under the alternative hypothesis between these analyses? Why?
Any insights greatly appreciated.

time.group goes from 1 to 7 instead of from 0 to 1.5 in the drug group, which means you are simulating a 4-5 times larger effect. Just rewrite the generate y part and the difference disappears.
#generate y
 y = with(df, (-10 + RE.i) + (-10 + RE.s + .75*(group == "drug") )*time  + e)


Thanks so much Lukas! I can't believe I missed that. Brilliant to have the error pointed out. Thanks.
